# DialogFragment(android)

Tags: android, android-sdk

Как обратиться к элементу внутри DialogFragment?
У меня в диалоге(View) есть еще поля ввода,когда пытаюсь обратиться к ним "стандартным образом"(как обычно обращаюсь к элементам фрагмента)
 :

```
EditText text = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.number_n);
```

Мне вылетает исключение что text = null и нельзя обратиться к этому элементу

> 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Ниже исходник самого фрагмента

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.loginform, null);
    EditText text = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.number_n);
    text.setText("123");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    return(builder.setTitle("Форма смены пользователя").setView(form)
            .setPositiveButton("Ок", this)
            .setNegativeButton("Отмена", null)
            .setNeutralButton("Забыли пароль?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "remember", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new CustomDialogFragmentRemember().show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "remember");
                }
            })
            .create());

}
```

Comment: Он у вас не спрашивает `text == null` или нет. Четко говорит что `text = null`. Насчет вопроса, я тут не вижу никакой `textView.setText()`

Comment: Возможно я не верно выразился, отредактировал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
        .inflate(R.layout.loginform, null);
EditText text = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.number_n);
text.setText("123");
```

попробуйте

```
form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
        .inflate(R.layout.loginform, null);
EditText text = form.findViewById(R.id.number_n);
text.setText("123");
```

Если вам все-таки надо изменять вью в активити, тогда ответ от TITAN подойдет.

Comment: Ваш вариант подошел,благодарю)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, не проверял.

Создайте метод в Activity, например

```
public void setMyText(String string){
   text.setText(string);
}
```

и в диалоговом окне

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.loginform, null);

    MyActivity myActivity = new MyActivity();
    ((myActivity) getActivity()).setMyText("123");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    return(builder.setTitle("Форма смены пользователя").setView(form)
            .setPositiveButton("Ок", this)
            .setNegativeButton("Отмена", null)
            .setNeutralButton("Забыли пароль?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "remember", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new CustomDialogFragmentRemember().show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "remember");
                }
            })
            .create());

}
```

Comment: > `MyActivity myActivity = new MyActivity();`         

НИКОГДА так не делайте - это создаёт экземпляр, отрешённый от жизни(LifeCicle) приложения, что чревато досадными недоразумениями(ака NullPointerException, memory leak, etc.).

Comment: Больше не буду!)